# How to achieve this progress bar according to values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three progress bars. Based on the value I need to change the width of progress bars. Here I am using three ids for each progress bar. I need a common class for all these as ids causing redundancy of JavaScript. And also I am unable to change the width of progress bar based on the values.

```js
var progress = $('#1 .my-progress-value').html();
    $('#1 .my-progress').css("width", progress + "%");
    if (progress == 0) {
        $('#1 .my-progress').css("background-color", "lightgrey");
        $('#1 .my-progress-value').css("background-color", "lightgrey");
    } else if (progress < 50) {
        $('#1 .my-progress').css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
        $('#1 .my-progress').css("background-color", "green");
    }
    
    progress = $('#2 .my-progress-value').html();
    $('#2 .my-progress').css("width", progress + "%");
    if (progress == 0) {
        $('#2 .my-progress').css("background-color", "lightgrey");
    } else if (progress < 50) {
        $('#2 .my-progress').css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
        $('#2 .my-progress').css("background-color", "green");
    }
    progress = $('#3 .my-progress-value').html();
    $('#3 .my-progress').css("width", progress + "%");
    if (progress == 0) {
        $('#3 .my-progress').css("background-color", "lightgrey");
    } else if (progress < 50) {
        $('#3 .my-progress').css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
        $('#3 .my-progress').css("background-color", "green");
    }
});
```

```css
.my-progress-value {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 7pt;
  padding: 8px 5px 8px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -11px;
}

.my-progress-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.my-progress {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 8px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" id="1">
    <div class="my-progress-container">
      <div class="my-progress">
        <span class="my-progress-value">10%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="2">
    <div class="my-progress-container">
      <div class="my-progress">
        <span class="my-progress-value">30%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="3">
    <div class="my-progress-container">
      <div class="my-progress">
        <span class="my-progress-value">20%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[updated](http://jsfiddle.net/e8fqLdfy/) fiddle.

Comment: This fiddle doesn't work. I see that you tagged the question with `jquery-ui`, are you using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated code

```js
$('.my-progress').each(function(index) {
  var progress = $(this).find('.my-progress-value').html();
  $(this).css("width", progress);
  if (parseInt(progress) == 0) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");
  } else if (parseInt(progress) < 50) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
  }
});
```

```css
.my-progress-value {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 7pt;
  padding: 8px 5px 8px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -11px;
}
.my-progress-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.my-progress {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 8px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="my-progress-container">
      <div class="my-progress">
        <span class="my-progress-value">100%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="my-progress-container">
      <div class="my-progress">
        <span class="my-progress-value">30%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="my-progress-container">
      <div class="my-progress">
        <span class="my-progress-value">20%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18aLusgy/3/)

Comment: partially achieved.I need class instead of ids

Comment: i did not undarstand what you mean by 'I need class instead of ids '. please explain

Comment: if you have  observed `<div class="col-md-3" id="3">`we are passing ids like 1,2,3. I want a common class without passing that ids.

Comment: I have to show this progress bar on each iteration and the section also having the pagination. When I am going to next page progress bar is not visible and when I come back to previous page then also  progress bar is not visible

Comment: either you have to create fiddle/snippet for scenario in which you want to implement code or you have to manage code according to your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function like this

```
function setProgress(control) {
    var progress = $(control).find(".my-progress").html();
    $(control).find('.my-progress').css("width", progress + "%");
    if (progress == 0) {
        $(control).find('.my-progress').css("background-color", "lightgrey");
        $(control).find('.my-progress-value').css("background-color", "lightgrey");
    } else if (progress < 50) {
        $(control).find('.my-progress').css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
        $(control).find('.my-progress').css("background-color", "green");
    }
}
```

call the function as

Ex.

```
setProgress($("#1"));
setProgress($("#2"));
setProgress($("#3"))
```

with class

1). set a class name "**ProgressControl**" where you write Id field.

2).

```
function setProgress() {
        var control = $(".ProgressControl");
        var progress = $(control).find(".my-progress").html();
        $(control).find('.my-progress').css("width", progress + "%");
        if (progress == 0) {
            $(control).find('.my-progress').css("background-color", "lightgrey");
            $(control).find('.my-progress-value').css("background-color", "lightgrey");
        } else if (progress < 50) {
            $(control).find('.my-progress').css("background-color", "red");
        } else {
            $(control).find('.my-progress').css("background-color", "green");
        }
    }
```

3). call

```
setProgress();
```

Comment: I don't want to use Ids that's what I mentioned in question

Comment: **Note**: You do not have to call the `$` function like `$(control)`, you already send to `setProgress` function a `jQuery` object, so you can call `find` on `control` like this: `control.find('.my-progress')`

Comment: Where to call `setProgress()` ?I dont have any button I need to call  them inside a `foreach` loop with different values

Comment: Yes, call it in $.each loop and pass setProgress($(this));

Comment: I think problem is you are generating html in loop with progress bar? If it is that then you first have to append Html then and then you can find control from $.

Answer (score 0):

Change function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".my-progress-value").each(function () {     // loop thru all .gains
            var progress = $(this).text();
            $(this).parent().css("width", progress + "%");
            if (progress < 30) {
                $(this).parent().css("background", "lightgrey");

            } else if (progress < 50) {
                $(this).parent().css("background", "red");
            } else {
                $(this).parent().css("background", "green");

            }
            $(this).html(progress + "%");
        });
    });
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="1">
                <div class="my-progress-container">
                    <div class="my-progress">
                        <span class="my-progress-value">20</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="2">
            <div class="my-progress-container">
                <div class="my-progress">
                    <span class="my-progress-value">49</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="3">
            <div class="my-progress-container">
                <div class="my-progress">
                    <span class="my-progress-value">100</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.my-progress-value {
            background-color: deepskyblue;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 100%;
            font-size: 7pt;
            padding: 8px 5px 8px 5px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: -11px;
        }

    .my-progress-container {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        padding-top: 4px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .my-progress {
        background-color: deepskyblue;
        width: 60%;
        height: 8px;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8fqLdfy/1/